# how to use .htaccess to redirect all http traffic to https AND www.domain.com

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've tried several solutions posted here, none of them seem to work - I just get redirect errors.

What I am trying to do is redirect all traffic to https for:

```
http://domain.com
http://www.domain.com
https://domain.com
http://alias.com
http://www.alias.com
https://alias.com
```

should all go to: https: // www.domain.com

currently addresses starting like: http: // www won't redirect to https.

here is the htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Fix Apache internal dummy connections from breaking [(site_url)] cache
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*internal\ dummy\ connection.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [F,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} .
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.mydomain.com/$1 [R=301,L] 

# Exclude /assets and /manager directories from rewrite rules
RewriteRule ^(manager|assets) - [L]

# For Friendly URLs
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^myalias.ca$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.myalias.ca$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "https\:\/\/mydomain\.com" [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^myotheralias.ca$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.myotheralias.ca$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "https\:\/\/mydomain\.com" [R=301,L]
```

Comment: If all requests should be redirected to https://mydomain.com why bother for the HTTP_HOST?

Answer (score 0):

You should get rid of the www redirects at the bottom:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^myalias.ca$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.myalias.ca$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "https\:\/\/mydomain\.com" [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^myotheralias.ca$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.myotheralias.ca$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "https\:\/\/mydomain\.com" [R=301,L]
```

Don't need them, you just need a single redirect at the top, replace:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} .
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.mydomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

with

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.mydomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.mydomain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

This should take care of all the redirects.

Comment: no - this still gives me a redirect loop. even if I remove everything but the three lines you provided [well with rewrite engine still on]

Comment: @SeanKimball there's something else redirecting other than what's in the htaccess file then. The rules only redirect if either HTTPS is off or the domain isn't www.mydomain.com. On my apache test server, this causes no loops.